# How do I revoke a token using Ember Simple Auth and redirect to the homepage?

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I have an Ember app using Ember Simple Auth. I need to revoke tokens on the server side, which I can do easy enough by setting the `revoked_at` column, in the `oauth_access_tokens` table, to a timestamp.

This causes the server to respond to Ember with a 401, which is great. However, Ember Simple Auth does not seem to fire the `authorizationFailed` action in the application route. I put a simple debugger in the action to test if it's getting hit.

What I want to happen is trigger any kind of authorization error to hit this action, which would allow me to manually run `invalidate()` if it hasn't done so yet, and redirect them to a login page.

Thanks.

Comment: You are mixing in the `ApplicationRouteMixin` in the application route?

Comment: Yes, and everything else works fine (sessionAuthenticationSucceeded, sessionAuthenticationFailed).